# Specifying Kubernetes version for Azure Container Service

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-container-service

Does anyone know if it is possible to specify the Kubernetes version when deploying ACS Kubernetes flavour?

If so how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the supported resource provider in ARM you cannot specify the version. However, if you use http://github.com/Azure/acs-engine you can do so. ACS Engine is the open source code we (I work for MS) use to drive Azure Container Service. Using this code you have much more flexibility than you do through the published resource provider, but it's a harder onramp. For instructions see https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/blob/master/docs/kubernetes.md

See examples at https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/tree/master/examples/kubernetes-releases

Comment: Superb! That worked many thanks! For any readers - It doesn't seem to make a 'container service' resource more just VM's and subnets etc pre-configured for Kubernetes

Comment: Except that the dashboard and DNS pods are failing to start on v1.4.6 - slightly frustrating

Comment: There is no parameter `kubectlVersion` in that file anymore?

Comment: You can see some examples for different K8s version in https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/tree/master/examples/kubernetes-releases, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should use acs-engine and follow the deploy guide in the repo (https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/blob/master/docs/kubernetes/deploy.md).

In the deploy guide they use the file `examples/kubernetes.json` and in that file there's - 

`"orchestratorProfile": {
  "orchestratorType": "Kubernetes"
}`

You can also add the field `"orchestratorRelease": "1.7"` for Kubernetes 1.7.

To view the whole list of releases available you can use the `acs-engine` executable and run `acs-engine orchestrators` that prints all of them.

Other examples can be found in https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/tree/master/examples/kubernetes-releases